# How do I install and use Groundwork CSS

Tags: css-frameworks

I've been looking around at some CSS frameworks and I really like the look of the [Groundwork CSS](http://groundwork.sidereel.com/) framework because it has a nice responsive layout. However I downloaded the source code and I'm a bit lost. I'm used to using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and and I really love it's documentation (the instructions on scaffolding are helpful to beginners), bit I don't really know how to use Groundwork.

How do I get started with using the Groundwork CSS framework?

Comment: What you are doing, you have on Groundwork site great documentation?

Comment: I find that the documentation explains the features of the site well, but it doesn't explain the installation of Groundwork itself as we'll as I'd like it to

Comment: For example, Twitter Bootstrap has an entire page explaining how to install the framework

Comment: download it and look into index.html and you will see how to do it

Comment: Ok. I'm used to the Twitter Bootstrap way of doing things where you just copy and paste a couple of CSS files, but Groundwork is clearly different. Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking at the source code now and I'm wondering what directories are safe to delete (to reduce clutter) if I don't need them. Can I delete the `templates` and `tests` directories?

Comment: You better use different css framework. This one is great http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: I'll have a look at that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groundwork, like Bootstrap, is a web-development framework, not just a set of CSS docs. They both include a set of style-sheets, java-script files, misc icons etc, and one or more HTML docs to bring it all together.Installation is simple; download the framework, rename the folder to "MyCoolNewSite", start editing.

As Michal stated, the "index/html" doc that comes with the framework has lots to look at to help you get started.  They also have what looks to be pretty solid documentation on their site, starting here:  http://groundwork.sidereel.com/?url=grid

The site has now changed to: http://groundworkcss.github.io/